# How do I calculate a blended fee?

Tags: javascript, math

I am attempting to calculate an investment management fee using a fee schedule. For example, let's say the investment amount is $5,000,000 and this is the fee schedule:

- 1,000,000 & Less: 1.00%
- 2,000,000: 0.75%
- 3,000,000: 0.50%
- 3,000,001+: 0.25%

Where dollars under 1,000,000 are charged 1.00% and dollars over $3,000,000 are charged 0.25%. I need to come up with the blended price using javascript (The answer in this case would be 0.55% or $27,500 in dollars).

How do you get the answer if the amount we're using as an example is $5,000,000 and the fee schedule above?

- $1,000,000 * 0.0100 = $10,000 (Fee for first $1m)
- $1,000,000 * 0.0075 = $7,500  (Fee for second $1m)
- $1,000,000 * 0.0050 = $5,000  (Fee for third $1m)
- $2,000,000 * 0.0025 = $5,000  (Everything over $3m)

So to manage the $5,000,000, the cost would be the total of the fees above ($27,500). And $27,500 / $5,000,000 = 0.55% which is our "blended fee".

The caveat, is not every fee schedule looks exactly like this. Some have different fees and limits.

What are the results of my research into this problem so far? I have not found a quality example of a function that could accomplish this on SO. It seems all tiered pricing calculations on SO only identify a single price for a given quantity of items, not a blended price though like I am trying to achieve here.

My fee schedule would potentially look something like this array:

```
fee_schedule: [
{ fee: 0.0100, limit: 1000000},
{ fee: 0.0075, limit: 2000000},
{ fee: 0.0050, limit: 3000000},
{ fee: 0.0025, limit: Infinity}
]
```

This is the direction I started down, but hit a wall in my head because I saw myself writing a ridiculously long function.

```
function determineFee(schedule, amount) {
   schedule.forEach(tier => {
    if (amount <= tier.limit) {
     // is this a path I should go down?
    }
   }
  //
}
```

Comment: I think it would help to say more explicitly how the different rates are combined and also how did you get the result 27,500 in your example.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thanks for that suggestion, I will add that right now.

Comment: I really don't see how that `4000000` limit is supposed to work.  The other limits show a top of their range.  This one seems meaningless.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, it is, i take `Infinity` for it. btw, a limit for the groups would work better.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yeah, probably should have just put "And over" there instead of $4m. I've updated the question to reflect that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: A data structure such as this seems much cleaner: `[{fee: 0.01000, high: 1000000}, {fee: 0.0075, low: 1000000, high: 2000000}, {fee: 0.0050, low: 2000000, high: 3000000}, {fee: 0.0025, low: 3000000}]`, with initial `0` and final `Infinity` implied or explicitly added.

Comment: That edit, adding `Infinity` is much cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build the delta of the last or zero and actual limit or if it is the last element take `Infinity`, for using the fee for the rest of the left over value.

Then make a check if the value is smaller then the delta. If true, calculate the fee for the rest value and end the loop.

Otherwise calculate the fee from the delta, decrement the value with the delta and assign the limit as last value, for having this value for the next loop.

```js
function getFee(value) {
    var fee = 0;

    fee_schedule.some((o, i, a) => {
        var delta = i + 1 === a.length
                ? Infinity
                : o.limit - (a[i - 1] && a[i - 1].limit || 0);

        if (value < delta) {
            fee += value * o.fee;
            return true;
        }
        fee += delta * o.fee;
        value -= delta;
    });

    return fee;
}

var fee_schedule = [{ fee: 0.0100, limit: 1000000 }, { fee: 0.0075, limit: 2000000 }, { fee: 0.0050, limit: 3000000 }, { fee: 0.0025, limit: 4000000 }],
    value = 5000000,
    fee = getFee(value);

console.log(fee);
```

For a shorter approach, you could change the data set and use only the slot size of the limits with one million for the first three itmes and `Infinity` for the last.

```js
function getFee(value) {
    var sum = 0;

    fee_schedule.some(({ fee, limit }) => {
        var v = value < limit ? value : limit;
        sum += v * fee;
        return !(value -= v);
    });

    return sum;
}

var fee_schedule = [{ fee: 0.0100, limit: 1000000 }, { fee: 0.0075, limit: 1000000 }, { fee: 0.0050, limit: 1000000 }, { fee: 0.0025, limit: Infinity }],
    value = 5000000,
    fee = getFee(value);

console.log(fee);
```

Comment: Why `some`?  `forEach` would seem to be more idiomatic.

Comment: because of the early exit with smaller values.

Comment: I think your first example fits my use case much better than the second. I toyed with just using the deltas as the `limit`, but to end-users actually setting a true `limit` is better for them.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another possibility:

```js
const blended = (schedule) => (amount) =>
  schedule.reduce ((sum, {fee, limit}, idx, sched) => {
    const top = Math.min (limit, amount)
    const bottom = idx == 0 ? 0 : sched[idx - 1].limit
  
    return sum + (top > bottom ? fee * (top - bottom) : 0)
  }, 0)

const blendedFee = (schedule) => {
  const calc = blended(schedule)
  return (amount) => calc(amount) / amount
}

const fee_schedule = [
  { fee: 0.0100, limit: 1000000},
  { fee: 0.0075, limit: 2000000},
  { fee: 0.0050, limit: 3000000},
  { fee: 0.0025, limit: Infinity}
]

console.log (blended (fee_schedule) (5000000))
console.log (blendedFee (fee_schedule) (5000000))
```

Note that these are curried, so you can store a reference to `blended (fee_schedule)` or `blendedFee (fee_schedule)` if you will need to reuse these for various loan amounts.

This does not include the clever early escape of Nina's answer, but I think it's easier to follow.

Comment: Thanks, Scott. I'd agree, much easier to follow! Which is super helpful for a novice like myself!